# SKAction repeating each frame for count?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

Does anyone know of a way in Sprite Kit to repeat an action each frame using a count? I was hoping the example below would work but all the repeats happen in the same update cycle.

```
SKAction *helloAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"HELLO!");
}];
SKAction *repeatBlock = [SKAction repeatAction:helloAction count:10];
[self runAction:repeatBlock];
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[14972:70b] -[MyScene update:]
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] HELLO!
[14972:70b] -[MyScene update:]
[14972:70b] -[MyScene update:]
[14972:70b] -[MyScene update:]
[14972:70b] -[MyScene update:]
```

Alternatively I looked at (See below) but this is based on a duration not a specified number of calls, so it all depends on your framerate (which I don't believe you can access). If your running at 20FPS you get 10 "HELLO AGAIN!"s if your at 60FPS then you get 30.

```
SKAction *helloAction = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:0.5 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
    NSLog(@"HELLO AGAIN!");
}];
[self runAction:helloAction];
```

## EDIT:

It would seem that I was on the right track with `SKAction repeatAction:count:`, where I was going wrong was that `NSLog(@"HELLO!");` (or any calculation you might do in the block) is an instantaneous action. If this is the case Sprite Kit repeats the action on the current frame only. The answer is to make the `SKAction` none instantaneous by adding a small delay via a sequence, now Sprite Kit executes the block once for each of the next 10 frames.

```
- (void)testMethod {
    SKAction *myAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"BLOCK ...");
    }];
    SKAction *smallDelay = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.001];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[myAction, smallDelay]];
    SKAction *repeatSequence = [SKAction repeatAction:sequence count:10];
    [self runAction:repeatSequence];
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
[399:60b] BLOCK ...
[399:60b] -[MyScene update:]
```

Comment: that solution doesn't work anymore with iOS 9.

Comment: for iOS 9 i set the delay to 1/60.0

Comment: note that you can trivially use the `Update()` function ***in the scene*** if that helps.  Idiotically, Apple forgot the update function ***in the sprites***.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger frameCounter;

- (void)didEvaluateActions
{
     if (self.frameCounter < 10){
          [self runAction:(SKAction *) yourAction];
          self.frameCounter++;
     }
     // frameCounter to be set to 0 when we want to restart the update for 10 frames again
}
```

method of the SKScene object, which is called exactly once per frame as long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused.

By default, this method does nothing. Your should override it in your scene subclass and perform any necessary updates to the scene.

[SKScene Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didEvaluateActions)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I only want the action to be called once for each of the next 10 frames. What you have here will get called once per frame forever.

Comment: Sorry I missed you needed it every 10 frames! I updated the answer - I assume you can still use this method (as it allows you to count the exact number of frames) and you can use a counter to execute the action every 10 frames only. Could this work?

Comment: The runBlock action here is superfluous. This if framecounter code already runs every frame for the next 10 frames. Now you only need to write the code directly in this method or send a message to another object to perform the task.

Comment: I updated the answer: definitely you just have to run in the if statement any actions you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys, I have edited my question to show my findings ... Much appreciated.